# Pandas generate new column function based on condition problem

Tags: python, pandas

```
def user_group(c):
  if c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] < 360.0:
    return 'Ocassional'
  elif (c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] >= 360.0) & (c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] <= 719.0)]:
    return 'Part_Time'
  elif c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] >=720.0:
    return 'Full_Time'
  else:
    return 'Undefined'

df['user_group'] = df.apply(user_group, axis=1)
```

I get the following error below, because of the elif part where I add a condition between two values to classify these users as **Part-Time**. I'm not sure what to do.

```
KeyError: False
```

Comment: Maybe just use `and` instead of `&`??

Comment: @RiccardoBucco That's not the issue, `&` works fine for booleans. They are getting a `KeyError` so it is a misplaced bracket issue.

Comment: @user12625679 The code you posted wouldn't give that error because there is a mismatched `]` which will give `SyntaxError` first. So please share the exact code that gave this error, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here seems need remove last `]`:

```
def user_group(c):
  if c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] < 360.0:
    return 'Ocassional'
  elif (c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] >= 360.0) & (c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] <= 719.0):
    return 'Part_Time'
  elif c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] >=720.0:
    return 'Full_Time'
  else:
    return 'Undefined'

df['user_group'] = df.apply(user_group, axis=1)
```

You can also improve solution for processing one column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE':[10,500,800,np.nan]})
def user_group(x):
  if x < 360.0:
    return 'Ocassional'
  elif x <= 719.0:
    return 'Part_Time'
  elif x >=720.0:
    return 'Full_Time'
  else:
    return 'Undefined'

df['user_group'] = df['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'].apply(user_group)

print (df)
   HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE  user_group
0                     10.0  Ocassional
1                    500.0   Part_Time
2                    800.0   Full_Time
3                      NaN   Undefined
```

Or here is possible use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df['user_group1'] = pd.cut(df['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'], 
                           bins=[-np.inf, 360,720,np.inf], 
                           labels=['Ocassional','Part_Time','Full_Time'],
                           right=False).astype(str).fillna('Undefined')
```

---

```
df['user_group1'] = pd.cut(df['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'], 
                           bins=[-np.inf, 360,720,np.inf], 
                           labels=['Ocassional','Part_Time','Full_Time'],
                           right=False)

df['user_group1'] = df['user_group1'].cat.add_categories(['Undefined']).fillna('Undefined')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use and instead of & for it Returns True if both statements are true.

```
 elif (c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] >= 360.0) and (c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] <= 719.0)]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your problem. Below code is working fine for me, in dataframe df HOUR_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE column is necessary.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE']=100

def user_group(c):
    if c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] < 360.0:
        return 'Ocassional'
    elif c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] >= 360.0 & (c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] <= 719.0):
        return 'Part_Time'
    elif c['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'] >=720.0:
        return 'Full_Time'
    else:
        return 'Undefined'

df['user_group'] = df.apply(user_group, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Version using lambda and arithmetic-logical expression and with variable number of ranges:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE':
                  [np.NaN, 12, 360, -10, np.nan, 450, 720, 965, 1200]}, dtype=object)
ranges = [360, 720, 900, 950, 1000]
# labels count must be len(ranges)+2
labels = ['Undefined', 'Ocassional', 'Part_Time', 'Full_Time', 'Extra_Time', 'Hero_Time', 'Unreal_Time']

df['user_group'] = df['HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE'].apply(
    # the arithmetic-logical expression below forms the index of the label in the list
    lambda c: labels[(1 + sum([c >= x for x in ranges])) * (c is not np.NaN)])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  HOURS_ONLINE_CUMULATIVE   user_group
0                     NaN    Undefined
1                      12   Ocassional
2                     360    Part_Time
3                     -10   Ocassional
4                     NaN    Undefined
5                     450    Part_Time
6                     720    Full_Time
7                     965    Hero_Time
8                    1200  Unreal_Time
```